# How to check a int variable is modified or not?

Tags: c++

I've a integer variable (whose initial value I don't know) that is passed to a function, which increments/modifies the variable by 'one' or 'zero' on certain conditions. Is it possible to check weather the variable got modified or not after the function call?.

IDE: MSVC 2012

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you are using Visual Studio, you can put a "data breakpoint" that will break when a variable's value changes.

Comment: Specify your IDE and debugger.

Comment: Return `true` or `false` depending on whether is was modified.

Comment: The answer is "it depends". If you pass by value, the answer is "No". If you pass by reference, the answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
void modify(int& var) {
  if (certainConditions) {
    var++;
  }
}

int oldValue = myValue;
modify(myValue);
if (oldValue != myValue) {
   //modified
}
```

Or as @juanchopanza suggested return a bool if value is modified, then you don't have to pass a reference

```
bool modify(int var) {
  if (certainConditions) {
    var++;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


if (modify(myValue)) {
   //modified
}
```

Comment: I don't know the initial value.

Comment: Yeah see the second sample, you don't need the initial value, if you are just returning a bool. Also how can you not know the initial value if you are passing it to the function :)

Comment: If you don't pass it by reference, you cannot change it.  Your second version just changes a local copy, which is destroyed when you return from the function.

Comment: Yeah I know, but he doesn't have to pass by reference if he doesn't want to see the change outside the function. Returning a bool will just tell him if the value was modified inside the function. Obviously the modify function should do more than just incrementing a local var that gets discarded upon return.

Answer (score 0):

What about using another variable?
It's likely that you have a tiny bit of extra memory remaining for this operation

Pseudocode:

```
int oldvalue = yourUnknownVariable;

func(yourUnknownVariable);

if(yourUnknownVariable==oldvalue)
{
     // not modified
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this is to use a `bool` return value:

```
bool modifyvar(int& var)
{
    bool ret = false;
    if(condition)
    {
        var++;
        ret = true;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you are already returning something, you can instead return a `tuple<T, bool>`, modify a global variable (not recommended, but how the C library often deals with this type of problem), pass a reference to a boolean as a parameter or return a `struct` or `class` with all the relevant values if you need to return quite a few different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assign the value of the variable into another one *before* invocation.
int oldValue = varValue;
//your function invocation happens here.
//NOTE: you are probably passing a reference of the integer to it.
invokeMyFunction(varValue);
//Compare the old with the current value of the variable
if(oldValue != varValue)
{
  //Code executed if value modified here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int value = 1;
cin>>"Your variable was modified";

Or

int value =1;
//do somethings with  variable **value**, maybe **value =2;** or what you have to do.

if(value!=1)
cout>>"My value was modified";
else
cout>>"My value wasn`t modified";